# gethostbyaddr in perl is returning empty?

Tags: perl

Hi I am using perl `$ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'}` to get ip address . It will return the ipaddress 
But when i am using

```
local($ip_address) = $ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'};
$ip_address =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
local(@bytes) = split(/\./,$ip_address);
local($packaddr) = pack("C4",@bytes);
local($host_name) = (gethostbyaddr($packaddr,2))[0];
print $host_name;
```

it is not giving any host name , instead it is returning nothing .
Any help??

Comment: I think `$packaddr` may need to be converted the right byte order using [`inet_aton`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.0/functions/gethostbyaddr.html) beforehand.

Comment: inet_aton($packaddr) ??

Comment: `$packaddr = inet_aton "ip in dotted form"`.

Comment: no i tried that too using use Socket.. no use

Answer (score 1):

All those `local` should be `my`<sup>[1]</sup>, `2` should be `AF_INET` (exported by the Socket module), and you could simplify things by using Socket's `inet_aton`, but your code works fine. For example, passing `173.194.43.88` outputs `yyz08s09-in-f24.1e100.net`. If it doesn't return an answer, it's because there isn't one to return.

What follows is much better code. It also avoids doing a reverse lookup if the web server's already done it for you.

```
use Socket qw( AF_INET inet_aton );
my $remote_addr = $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR};
my $remote_host = $ENV{REMOTE_HOST}
   // gethostbyaddr(inet_aton($remote_addr), AF_INET)
   // $remote_addr;
print "$remote_host\n";
```

---

1. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: if you're one of those `Modern::Perl` folks, that's probably fine, too.

Comment: there isn't one to return?? I want host name of computer

Comment: What do you call a computer's host name?

Comment: computer name which can be person's name

Comment: What do you mean by "computer name"?

Comment: right click on computer go to properties.. there u will find computer name

Comment: This is painful to watch. Let's skip to the end. The hostnames that `gethostbyaddr` knows about are the ones in the DNS. And possibly the local `/etc/hosts`. The name that a remote machine calls *itself* is not something you can look up, unless it has published that name in the DNS.

Comment: Is it possible to get that name?? Yes that is published in DNS

Comment: Do you have any independent confirmation that the reverse DNS for the IP address in question is working? If it's not a big secret, maybe you could tell us what the address is.

Comment: No, that is not published in DNS. That has nothing to do with DNS whatsoever. It's an OS-specific variable. A computer's registry can be accessed remotely with proper credentials. Otherwise, I think NetBIOS provides that value.

Comment: If instead you want something from the DNS system, you'll have to say what, but we've already covered there is no name associated with that address in DNS, which is to say there is no name in the PTR record of that IP address. (We can confirm it if you provide the IP address.)

Comment: @Wumpus Q. Wumbley, It can be looked up. What a machine calls itself cannot be published to DNS. It's not even a domain name. Maybe it was painful to watch, but necessary to give a correct response.

Comment: It's possible that SSS is using a system that propagates the Windows "computer name" through the DHCP server to the DNS server as a dynamic update. Such things do exist. But it's also possible that SSS is just too confused to answer the questions accurately.